# Sencha touch navigation issue in back button

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

I have tried to create a navigation in sencha touch. I have come a cross a situation which i can't figure out. please help me to figure out why the event listeners are not working when i hit back button.

I have created an main container containing a separate place for adding the panels on the fly.

Back and next buttons are in another panel in main view.

when my add function fires it adds the panel's functionality and works fine for one time. But when i navigate through back button the functionality is not working namely the 'piccsClicked', 'cvcsClicked'; where an image is changed. And there are some other functions

Please help me to understand the issue and a solution.

My guess is since i'm creating a panel when i hit back button using 
    xtype: "" + newPanel + "" 
it creates a brand new panel and the functions are not applied to that. Please help me to  solve this issue.

following are the codes

```
 var current = 1;
 var myPanel = new Array("panelOne", "panelOneP", "panelTwoP", "panelThreeP", "panelFourP", "panelFiveP", "panelOneC", "panelTwoC", "panelThreeC", "panelFourCVC", "panelFiveC", "panelSixCGraph", "panelSixPGraph");

 Ext.define("myApp.controller.MainController", {
     extend: "Ext.app.Controller",

     config: {
         refs: {
             main: '#main',
             backButton: '#backButton',
             nextButton: '#nextButton',
             panelArea: '#panelArea', //this panel is in main view along with some other panels, among the other panels there is a panel which contains the back and next buttons
             panelOne: '#panelOne', // these are the views extending Ext.Panel
             panelOneP: '#panelOneP',
             panelTwoP '#panelTwoP',
             panelThreeP: '#panelThreeP',
             panelFourP: '#panelFourP',
             panelFiveP: '#panelFiveP',
             panelSixPGraph: '#panelSixPGraph',
             panelOneC: '#panelOneC',
             panelTwoC: '#panelTwoC',
             panelThreeC: '#panelThreeC',
             panelFourC: '#panelFourC',
             panelFiveC: '#panelFiveC',
             panelSixCGraph: '#panelSixCGraph',
             piccs: '#piccs', // these two are images in the panelOne
             cVCs: '#CVCs',
         },

         control: {
             cVCs: {
                 tap: 'cvcsClicked'
             },
             piccs: {
                 tap: 'piccsClicked'
             },
             backButton: {
                 tap: 'navigateBack'
             },
             nextButton: {
                 tap: 'navigateNext'
             },
         },
     },

     navigateBack: function () {
         current = current - 1;
         this.addPanel(myPanel[current]);
     },

     navigateNext: function () {
         current = current + 1;
         this.addPanel(myPanel[current]);
     },

     addPanel: function (newPanel) {

         this.getPanelArea().removeAt(0);

         }
         var myNewPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
             items: [{
                 xtype: "" + newPanel + ""  // every view is given ID exactly as in the array
             }]
         });
         this.getPanelArea().add(myNewPanel);
     },

     piccsClicked: function () {
         var current = this.getPiccs().getSrc();
         if (current == 'resources/images/checkBoxUnchecked.jpg') {
             this.getPiccs().setSrc('resources/images/checkBoxChecked.jpg');
         } else {
             this.getPiccs().setSrc('resources/images/checkBoxUnchecked.jpg');
         }
     },

     cvcsClicked: function () {
         var current = this.getCVCs().getSrc();
         if (current == 'resources/images/checkBoxUnchecked.jpg') {
             this.getCVCs().setSrc('resources/images/checkBoxChecked.jpg');
         } else {
             this.getCVCs().setSrc('resources/images/checkBoxUnchecked.jpg');
         }
     },

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same trouble. I resolved it by doing this:

1. In your controller, create a new `ref`:

   ```
   backToNav: 'myNavXtypeName button[text=Back]'
   ```
2. In the same controller, link the ref to a `control`:

   ```
   backToNav: {
           tap: 'backToNav'
   }
   ```
3. Finally create the controller method that implements the navigation view's pop functionality.

   ```
   backToNav: function() {
           Ext.getCmp('myNavXtypeName').pop()
   }
   ```

Done. 
[Read more about refs and controls here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/core_concepts/controllers.html)

Answer (score -1):

Be careful where you put commas `,` and check if everything is closed `{` with `}` brackets correctly.

Basically you shouldn't put any `,` before closing brackets `}` or `]`
like you did at the end:

```
    },
});
```

or after `'#CVCs',`

```
    cVCs: '#CVCs',
},
```

Also are you sure you want to put `},` after `this.getPanelArea().add(myNewPanel);`?

```
    this.getPanelArea().add(myNewPanel);
},
```

This will close your controller definition but you have two more function `piccsClicked` and `cvcsClicked` that should go before the closing `},`.

Moreover closing the controller should be `});` and not `},` *(might have been left there accidentaly)*.

#### Try this:

```
var current = 1;
var myPanel = new Array("panelOne", "panelOneP", "panelTwoP", "panelThreeP", "panelFourP", "panelFiveP", "panelOneC", "panelTwoC", "panelThreeC", "panelFourCVC", "panelFiveC", "panelSixCGraph", "panelSixPGraph");

Ext.define("myApp.controller.MainController", {
    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",

    config: {
        refs: {
            main: '#main',
            backButton: '#backButton',
            nextButton: '#nextButton',
            panelArea: '#panelArea', //this panel is in main view along with some other panels, among the other panels there is a panel which contains the back and next buttons
            panelOne: '#panelOne', // these are the views extending Ext.Panel
            panelOneP: '#panelOneP',
            panelTwoP '#panelTwoP',
            panelThreeP: '#panelThreeP',
            panelFourP: '#panelFourP',
            panelFiveP: '#panelFiveP',
            panelSixPGraph: '#panelSixPGraph',
            panelOneC: '#panelOneC',
            panelTwoC: '#panelTwoC',
            panelThreeC: '#panelThreeC',
            panelFourC: '#panelFourC',
            panelFiveC: '#panelFiveC',
            panelSixCGraph: '#panelSixCGraph',
            piccs: '#piccs', // these two are images in the panelOne
            cVCs: '#CVCs'
        },

        control: {
            cVCs: {
                tap: 'cvcsClicked'
            },
            piccs: {
                tap: 'piccsClicked'
            },
            backButton: {
                tap: 'navigateBack'
            },
            nextButton: {
                tap: 'navigateNext'
            }
        }
    },

    navigateBack: function () {
        current = current - 1;
        this.addPanel(myPanel[current]);
    },

    navigateNext: function () {
        current = current + 1;
        this.addPanel(myPanel[current]);
    },

    addPanel: function (newPanel) {
        this.getPanelArea().removeAt(0);
    },
 
    var myNewPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        items: [{
            xtype: "" + newPanel + ""  // every view is given ID exactly as in the array
        }]
    });

    this.getPanelArea().add(myNewPanel);

    piccsClicked: function () {
        var current = this.getPiccs().getSrc();
        if (current == 'resources/images/checkBoxUnchecked.jpg') {
            this.getPiccs().setSrc('resources/images/checkBoxChecked.jpg');
        } else {
            this.getPiccs().setSrc('resources/images/checkBoxUnchecked.jpg');
        }
    },

    cvcsClicked: function () {
        var current = this.getCVCs().getSrc();
        if (current == 'resources/images/checkBoxUnchecked.jpg') {
            this.getCVCs().setSrc('resources/images/checkBoxChecked.jpg');
        } else {
            this.getCVCs().setSrc('resources/images/checkBoxUnchecked.jpg');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @benka thanks man, i was struggling with a back button on Sencha 2.1 spent almost a whole weekend trying to find out whats was the problem. I had a "," before a closing bracket, similar then here...

Comment: @saneera if this solved your problem you should accept the answer